# There seems to be an ArgumentException when I'm creating a Bitmap object using the

Tags: c#, argumentexception

I'm trying to re-size my sprites to make them the proper size so they get drawn correctly, but I cant seem to find why I'm getting an unhandled ArgumentExepction when I'm making the new Bitmap object.

```
public static Image prepareImage(Image original, Size size)
{
     Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(original, size);
     return (Image)newImage;
}
```

Comment: Please include the complete exception traceback in your question

Comment: An ArgumentExepction exception means that you are passing a bag value to the `Bitmap` constructor.  Is `orignal` a valid image?  Is `size` a valid size (e.g. negative?)

Comment: the Image parameter that I'm using is from my Properties.Resources directory. I've used them from there before and i do not know what I'm doing differently. The size is set to 20x20

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in the way the Size object parameter was initialized. Changing that fixed the problem.